# Why this gives Token Manager Exception

Tags: parsing, javacc

I am using Lexical state in JavaCC parser to switch from one state to other, after it matches Token A1.

```
< DEFAULT > TOKEN :
{
    <A1 : "Hello"> : STATE2
    | <A2 : "World">
}

< STATE2 > TOKEN :
{
    <B1: "World"> : DEFAULT
}
```

When I try to parse Hello Wolrd, It throws Token Manager Error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in STATE2 there is no rule to match any prefix of `" Wolrd"`.  In case you meant `"Hello World"`, it is because there is no rule in STATE2 to match any prefix of `" World"`.

If you want to ignore spaces, add a rule

```
<DEFAULT, STATE2> SKIP : { " " }
```

Comment: Thank You, @Theodore . You are right I was missing the above rule for DEFAULT and STATE2.